# JMS Message wasn't deleted after it was received

Tags: jms

What can be the reason of this problem?

Connection, Session were closed at the end.

I use WebLogic as JMS Broker. And I didn't find autodelete after receive option in JMS Queue configuration.

Comment: Do you receive your message from a queue? Is it configured such that the message is deleted when delivered?

Comment: I use WebLogic as JMS Broker. And I didn't find this option in JMS Queue configuration.

Comment: Do you acknowledge your received messages by calling the `acknowledge` method of the javax.jms.Message interface?

Comment: session = conn.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE); - is the answer

Comment: Yes, auto_acknowledge is also an option